# Weird rendering issue

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2

I am facing a weird problem on some of the pages on my website. I get this screen for sometime and the issue gets resolved by itself after sometimes. Any idea what might be causing the issue.

Screenshot as seen on Chrome:
[image]

Here is the response header for the request:

```
Request URL:http://www.badmintonbuddy.com/Create
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headers
Accept:application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utmz=14266660.1293156873.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=badmintonbuddy; __utma=14266660.1914068399.1293156873.1296024615.1296061789.13; __utmc=14266660; __utmb=14266660.7.10.1296061789
Host:www.badmintonbuddy.com
Referer:http://www.badmintonbuddy.com/Create
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.237 Safari/534.10
Response Headers
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:1194
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 26 Jan 2011 17:30:52 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

and here is the HTML of the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head><title>



    Submit a Club



</title> 
        <meta name="description" content="Badminton, Badminton Clubs, Play Badminton, Badminton courts " /> 
        <meta name="keywords" content="Badminton, Badminton Clubs, Play Badminton, Badminton courts" /> 
    <link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    
    <!-- For LOCAL>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAATcytSR8mvGpZGALaUc8OOhT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxQElXY6qUXmKmYpeVwhVtW50LGAQQ"></script--> 

    <!--For PROD--> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAATcytSR8mvGpZGALaUc8OOhSZOUWVEB7juxYWb997FACJmh8mbhSnemR4drJ-L8ZQftUNHVhtn9Ph4g"></script> 


    <!-- jQuery UI Components--> 
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    

    <!-- jQuery UI Components--> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div class="wrapper"> 
    <div class="page"> 
        <div id="header">            
            <div id="menucontainer"> 
            <a href="/">            
            <img class="logo" src="../../Content/logo.jpg" alt="BadmintonBuddy"/> 
            </a>   
            <ul id="menu">              
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li> 
                <li><a href="/Create">Submit a Club</a></li> 
                <li><a href="/Feedback">Feedback</a></li> 
                <li><a href="/About">About</a></li> 
            </ul> 
            </div> 
        </div> 

        <div id="main"> 


    <script src="../../Scripts/Map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    

    <script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">



        $(document).ready(function() {



            addWatermark();



            $('input:submit, input:button').button();



            $('a #locate').click(function() {

                loadLocation();

            });



            $('#Country').autocomplete({

                source: "GetCountry",

                minLength: 0

            });



            $('#State').autocomplete({

                source: function(request, response) {

                    $.ajax({

                        url: "GetState",

                        dataType: "json",

                        data: {

                            term: request.term,

                            country: $('#Country').val()

                        },

                        success: function(data) {

                            response(data);

                        }

                    });

                },

                minLength: 2

            });



            $('#City').autocomplete({

                source: function(request, response) {

                    $.ajax({

                        url: "GetCity",

                        dataType: "json",

                        data: {

                            term: request.term,

                            state: $('#State').val()

                        },

                        success: function(data) {

                            response(data);



                        }

                    });

                },

                minLength: 2

            });



            $('#optional').accordion({

                collapsible: true,

                animated: 'bounceslide',

                active: false

            });



            $('.mapoptions').dialog({

                autoOpen: false,

                show: 'blind',

                width: 600,

                height: 500,

                resizable: false,

                title: "Preview Club Location",

                buttons: { "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }, "Add": function(event, ui) { fillAddress(); $(this).dialog("close"); } }

            });







            $('#preview').click(function() {

                loadLocation();

                return false;

            });



            $('#submit').click(function() {

                //watermark puts all the fields with some text

                //hence MVC validation would not work,

                //check mandatory fields and then submit if everything is good.                

                if (rgbToHex($('#ClubName').css('color')) == '#aaaaaa') {

                    $('#ClubName_validationMessage').html("Please enter Club Name").css('color', 'red'); ;

                    $('#ClubName_validationMessage').show();

                    return false;



                }

                else if (rgbToHex($('#Address').css('color')) == '#aaaaaa') {

                    $('#Address_validationMessage').html("Please enter Address for the Club").css('color', 'red'); ;

                    $('#Address_validationMessage').show();

                    return false;

                }

                $('input:text').each(function() {

                if (rgbToHex($(this).css('color')) == '#aaaaaa') {

                        $(this).val("");

                    }

                });



                $('textarea').each(function() {

                if (rgbToHex($(this).css('color')) == '#aaaaaa') {

                        $(this).val("");

                    }

                });



                $('#ClubName_validationMessage').hide();

                $('#Address_validationMessage').hide();

                return true;

            });

        });    





    </script>    

    <div id="submitdiv">

    <div id="clubform">



    <form action="/create" id="form0" method="post">



            <div class="editor-label">

                <b class="req">*</b><label for="Club Name">Club Name</label>                

            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">                

                <input class="padding5" id="ClubName" name="ClubName" size="50" type="text" value="" />                

                <span class="field-validation-valid" id="ClubName_validationMessage"></span>                               

            </div>            



            <div class="editor-label">                

                <label for="Country">Country</label>

            </div>

            <div class="editor-field"> 

                <input class="padding5" id="Country" name="City.State.Country.CountryName" size="50" type="text" value="" />               

                <span class="field-validation-valid" id="City_State_Country_CountryName_validationMessage"></span>                                               

            </div>            



            <div class="editor-label">

                <label for="State">State</label>

            </div>



            <div class="editor-field">

                <input class="padding5" id="State" name="City.State.StateName" size="50" type="text" value="" />                               

                <span class="field-validation-valid" id="City_State_StateName_validationMessage"></span>                                

            </div>



            <div class="editor-label">

                <label for="City">City</label>

            </div>



            <div class="editor-field">

                <input class="padding5" id="City" name="City.CityName" size="50" type="text" value="" /> 

                <span class="field-validation-valid" id="City_CityName_validationMessage"></span>                                              

            </div>           



            <div class="editor-label">

                <b class="req">*</b><label for="Address">Address</label>

            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">

                <input class="padding5" id="Address" name="Address" size="50" type="text" value="" />

                <span class="field-validation-valid" id="Address_validationMessage"></span>                

                <div id="locatemap">

                    <a href="javascript:loadLocation();"><img src="../../Content/map_icon.jpg" alt="Locate on map" height="40px" width="40px"/>

                    <p>Locate on Map</p></a>

                </div>                 

            </div>



            <div class="editor-label">

                <label for="Number of Courts">Number of Courts</label>

            </div>



            <div class="editor-field">

                <input class="padding5" id="City" name="Courts" size="50" type="text" value="" /> 

                <span class="field-validation-valid" id="Courts_validationMessage"></span>                                              

            </div>   



            <div class="editor-label">

                <label for="CourtSurface">CourtSurface</label>

            </div>



            <div class="editor-field">

                <select name="Surface">

                <option value="1">Wooden</option>

                <option value="2">Syntetic</option>

                <option value="3">Cement</option>

                <option value="4">Cement with Mat</option>

                <option value="5">Others</option>

                </select>

                <label id="lblSurface">Please Specify</label>

                <input display="none" id="Others" name="Others" type="text" value="" />

            </div>         



            <div class="editor-label">

                <label for="Website">Website</label>

            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">

                <input class="padding5" id="Website" name="Website" size="50" type="text" value="" />

                <span class="field-validation-valid" id="Website_validationMessage"></span>                

            </div>  



            <div class="editor-label">

                <label for="Email">Email</label><label for="(">(</label><a href="javascript:showHelp();"> Why?</a><label for=")">)</label>

            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">

                <input class="padding5" id="Email" name="Email" size="50" type="text" value="" />

                <span class="field-validation-valid" id="Email_validationMessage"></span>

            </div>           



            <input id="Owner" name="Owner" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Owner" type="hidden" value="false" />I am the owner of the club.



            <!--All optional would go in this collapsable UI-->

            <div id="optional">            

            <h3><a href="#">Add more details</a></h3>

            <div id="optionalfields">

            <div class="editor-label">

                <label for="PhoneNumber">PhoneNumber</label>

            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">

                <input class="padding5" id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber" size="50" type="text" value="" />

                <span class="field-validation-valid" id="PhoneNumber_validationMessage"></span>

            </div>







           <div class="editor-label">

                <label for="Fees">Fees</label>

            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">

                <input class="padding5" id="Fees" name="Fees" size="50" type="text" value="" />

                <span class="field-validation-valid" id="Fees_validationMessage"></span>

            </div>





            <div class="editor-label">

                <label for="Timings">Timings</label>

            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">

                <input class="padding5" id="Timings" name="Timings" size="50" type="text" value="" />

                <span class="field-validation-valid" id="Timings_validationMessage"></span>

            </div>





            <div class="editor-label">

                <label for="Description">Description</label>

            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">

                <textarea cols="40" id="Description" name="Description" rows="5">

</textarea>

                <span class="field-validation-valid" id="Description_validationMessage"></span>

            </div>



            </div>

            </div>

            <!--End of optional collapsable fields-->            

            <div id="captcha">

            <div class="editor-label padding5 detailshead">

                <label>Security Check:</label>

                <label>Type both words seperated by space below</label>

            </div>            

            <script type="text/javascript">

        var RecaptchaOptions = {

            theme : 'red',

            tabindex : 0

        };



</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfDnr8SAAAAAAj6KZ0E99d_-vtwgUiOxByyzV1x">



</script><noscript>

        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LfDnr8SAAAAAAj6KZ0E99d_-vtwgUiOxByyzV1x" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0">



        </iframe><br /><textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea><input name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" type="hidden" />

</noscript>            

            <div id="captchaerror" class="error">Sorry! Those aren't the correct words. Please verify again.</div> 

            </div>            

            <p>

                <input type="button" id="preview" value="Preview it on Map"/>                                

                <input type="button" id="create" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:validateCaptcha('form0');"/>

                <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="this.form.reset()" />

            </p>

    </form><script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[

if (!window.mvcClientValidationMetadata) { window.mvcClientValidationMetadata = []; }

window.mvcClientValidationMetadata.push({"Fields":[{"FieldName":"ClubName","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"ClubName_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[]},{"FieldName":"City.State.Country.CountryName","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"City_State_Country_CountryName_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[]},{"FieldName":"City.State.StateName","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"City_State_StateName_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[]},{"FieldName":"City.CityName","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"City_CityName_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[]},{"FieldName":"Address","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"Address_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[]},{"FieldName":"Courts","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"Courts_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[{"ErrorMessage":"The field Courts must be a number.","ValidationParameters":{},"ValidationType":"number"}]},{"FieldName":"Website","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"Website_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[]},{"FieldName":"Email","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"Email_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[]},{"FieldName":"PhoneNumber","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"PhoneNumber_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[]},{"FieldName":"Fees","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"Fees_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[]},{"FieldName":"Timings","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"Timings_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[]},{"FieldName":"Description","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"Description_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[]}],"FormId":"form0","ReplaceValidationSummary":false});

//]]>

</script>

    </div>

    <div class="mapoptions">

        <p><b>Move marker(<img alt="marker" src="http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png" height="15" width="15" />)on the map to change the location.Click Add once done.</b></p>

        <div id="mapDiv" style="height:350px">        

        </div>

    </div>



    </div>
        </div> 
        <div id="footer"> 
            <!-- Custom for Project --> 
    <script src="../../Scripts/Map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/Captcha.js"></script> 
            <script src="../../Scripts/Main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>            
            <!-- Custom for Project --> 
        </div>        
    </div>    
    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You are likely using the wrong encoding. Is this problem present on other computers too?

Comment: Yes, and if this is the issue with the wrong enconding how does it render correctly after sometime on the same computer and same browser without any changes?

Comment: The HTML of the page when this occurs would be good. I guess you're rendering something that sometimes goes wrong and messes up with the page. Save the static HTML source code when you have the effect and narrow it down by commenting blocks out, or post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, this is my output in Net tab of Firebug:-

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 27 Jan 2011 03:58:42 GMT
Content-Length: 1194
```

It's pointing to a 500 Internal server error, can you check it.